# Не срабатывает событие click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
<ul class="list">
  <li id="0">54546</li>
 </ul>
<div class="result"></div>
```

и `jQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add').click(function(){
    var i;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
       $('.list').append('<li id="'+i+'">Test</li>'); 
    }
  });

  $('li').click(function(event){
    $('.result').text($(event.target).text());
  });
});
```

На данный момент клик по `li` срабатывает только по элементу с `id=0`. Если добавить дополнительные элементы `li`, с помощью кнопки **Add**, то они работать не будут. Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы клик по другим элементам `li` срабатывал?

Comment: `$('.list').on("click", "li", function(event) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

В тот момент, когда загружается страница на элементы li ставится обработчик клика, но на новые элементы, которые создаются по клику на кнопку обработчик не ставится. Чтобы обработчик срабатывал нужно его поставить.

```
function liclick(event) {
  $('.result').text($(event.target).text());
}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#add').click(function(){ 
    var i;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){ 
      var el=$('<li id="'+i+'">Test</li>');
      $('.list').append(el);
      el.click(liclick);
    }
  }); 
  $('li').click(liclick);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать. Тогда можно немножко изменить, чтобы обработчик ставился только новым элементам. Сейчас поправлю

Comment: Да, так гораздо лучше.